# Xamarin Forms Entry Field is scaling larger then screen size in iOS

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `ContentPage` which displays E-Mail adresses. The Page is opened, when it got pushed on the Navigation Stack.

```
var contextToBind = new WorkOrderEMailViewModel(tempBoundItem.No, tempBoundItem.Name, tempBoundItem.Description1);
var page = new WorkOrderEMailPage() { BindingContext = contextToBind };
await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

The Object `WorkOrderEMailViewModel` has a property called `To`, which stores the mail adresses.

The Xaml look like this. The Entry field stores the mail adress.

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
   <Entry Text="{Binding BoundItem.To}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>
   <Button Text="..." VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Command="{Binding ListItemsButtonTappedCommand}"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

So here is where the problem starts. When the `To` has a very long value, the entry field scales greater then the screen is, so you could not see the end and the button next to the `Entry` field.

Following Screenshots will make it clear what i want. It is the first `Entry`.

This is how it looks like with short text and how it should look like with very long text.

[image: Pic1]

**And this is how it actually looks like.**

[image: Pic2]

I tried playing around with the `HorizontalOption`, but with no success.

### Update

Based on the recommendation from Clint Landry I changed the `xaml` to:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="40" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Entry Text="{Binding BoundItem.To}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Entry>
     <Button Text="..." Command="{Binding ListItemsButtonTappedCommand}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the page in a parent stacklayout with settings of VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill". Change the children to either a grid (recommended) or HorizontalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Horizontal". The full xaml would be helpful as it feels like other parent xaml tags are affecting this.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stackContent" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"    HorizontalOptions="Fill">
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
   <Entry Text="{Binding BoundItem.To}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>
   <Button Text="..." VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Command="{Binding ListItemsButtonTappedCommand}"></Button>
</StackLayout>
</Stacklayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I used a grid and will post the answer in the question.